# How to toggle the background color of several HTML elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

More or less the title, each element has a different class name.

HTML elements:

```
<section class = "top-nav">
<h3 class = "top-left-heading">Hot</h3>
<h3 class = "top-right-heading">Items</h3>
<h3 class = "bottom-left-heading">Interaction</h3>
<h3 class = "bottom-right-heading">Location</h3>
<section class = "footer">
```

Javascript function:

```
var theme
function toggleTheme(){
    var bars = document.querySelectorAll('.heading' + '.nav' + '.header' + 
'footer')
    if (theme == "blue"){
        for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){
            bars[i].style.backgroundColor = "#11C034";
        }
        theme = "green"
    }
    else{
        for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){
            bars[i].style.backgroundColor = "#428bca";
        }
        theme = "blue"
    }

}
```

Comment: You can affect more than one class name to an object.

Comment: Change '.heading' + '.nav' + '.header' + 'footer' to '.heading,.nav,.header,.footer'

Comment: You need `var bars = document.querySelectorAll('.top-nav h3, .header, .footer');`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector syntax is incorrect:

```
var bars = document.querySelectorAll('.heading' + '.nav' + '.header' + 'footer')
```

- First, this should be one big string with commas separating the different selectors that is passed to the method, not a
  concatenation of strings (unless you wanted to incorporate variable data, which you aren't doing).
- Second, the classes you reference aren't actually the classes you are
  using in your HTML.

The correct syntax would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".top-left-heading, .top-right-heading, .bottom-left-heading, .bottom-right-heading")
```

Next, there is no need at all for `if/then` or inline styles. Just set up classes for the themes you will need, set a default class (theme) on the HTML elements in question and then toggle the use of those classes via some trigger.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", toggleTheme);

function toggleTheme(){
  // Get all the headings into a node list and then convert that node list to an array
  var bars = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".top-left-heading, .top-right-heading, .bottom-left-heading, .bottom-right-heading"));

  // Loop through the array
  bars.forEach(function(bar){
    // Toggle the use of the classes
    bar.classList.toggle("green");
    bar.classList.toggle("blue");
  }); 
}
```

```css
.green {
  background-color :green;
  color:yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color :blue;
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<section class = "top-nav">
  <h3 class = "top-left-heading green">Hot</h3>
  <h3 class = "top-right-heading green">Items</h3>
  <h3 class = "bottom-left-heading green">Interaction</h3>
  <h3 class = "bottom-right-heading green">Location</h3>
<section class = "footer">

<button type="button">Toggle Theme</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better way is to just add the class `.theme-black` to the body element. Then just write the CSS for the elements given that base class, like this:

```
.top-nav {
    // basic CSS colors...
}
.theme-black .top-nav {
    background: #000;
}
```

This way you minimize JavaScript and let CSS do the styles.